# How to type hint type union as one or the other in typescript

Tags: typescript, react-context, union-types

I have a React context called "PageContext", this Page Context is different depending on the page loaded.

i.e. for Home Page it might have a property `description` and for the Search Page it would not.

```
const { pageContext }: { pageContext: FinderPageServerSideProps } =
        useContext(PageContext);
```

However, I keep getting error.

```
Type 'HomePageServerSideProps' is missing the following properties from type 'FinderPageServerSideProps': siteOptions, region, initialTab
```

I wanted to make a `as any as FinderPageServerSideProps` but I can't get it to work.

How can I hint that I know for sure that this context is of X type?

The pageContextState is hinted as follows:

```
export type PageContextState = {} & (
    | FinderPageServerSideProps
    | HomePageServerSideProps
);
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by hint why isn't `const { pageContext } =
        useContext(PageContext) as { pageContext: FinderPageServerSideProps }` good enough. If you don't have enough info in the type system to know the pageContext that is the best you can do. The `{} &` seems to try to replicate how you can hint at specific strings for a string type, but that does not work here. `T & {}` is basically just `T`  if `T` is an object type

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir yes thank you, that was what I was looking for I just didn't know what was the syntax